# error: Logcat capture failed: spawn ENOENT

Tags: java, android, node.js, appium

```
Starting Node Server 
info: Welcome to Appium v1.2.0 (REV e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5)
debug: Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"19","automationName":"Appium"}
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
info: LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"automationName":"Appium","platform":"Android","platformVersion":"19","app":"C:\\Users\\qadeer\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\convoTest\\app\\Convo.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"01899dd5c94c237a","browserName":"","app-package":"com.convo.android","app-activity":".ConvoMain","version":"4.4.2"}}
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session
debug: Request received with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"automationName":"Appium","platform":"Android","platformVersion":"19","app":"C:\\Users\\qadeer\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\convoTest\\app\\Convo.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"01899dd5c94c237a","browserName":"","app-package":"com.convo.android","app-activity":".ConvoMain","version":"4.4.2"}}
info: Starting android appium
debug: The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : platform, app-package, app-activity, version
debug: No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
debug: No appPackage desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
debug: Using local app from desired caps: C:\Users\qadeer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\convoTest\app\Convo.apk
debug: Creating new appium session baf82af5-dfab-4837-8fa0-a56da25fa1ec
debug: Using fast reset? true
debug: Preparing device for session
debug: Checking whether app is actually present
debug: Checking whether adb is present
debug: Using adb from D:\Soft backup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

info: Retrieving device
debug: Trying to find a connected android device
debug: Getting connected devices...
debug: executing: "D:\Soft backup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
debug: 1 device(s) connected
info: Found device 01899dd5c94c237a
debug: Setting device id to 01899dd5c94c237a
debug: Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
debug: executing: "D:\Soft backup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 01899dd5c94c237a wait-for-device
debug: executing: "D:\Soft backup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 01899dd5c94c237a shell "echo 'ready'"
debug: Starting logcat capture
error: Logcat capture failed: spawn ENOENT
debug: Stopping logcat capture
```

this is appium application server log i m getting this error

```
error: Logcat capture failed: spawn ENOENT
debug
```

: Stopping logcat capture

and my application get hanged 
here is my capabilities

```
    File app = new File( "app/Sat.apk");

            if(app.exists())
                System.out.println("exsist");

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");
            capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Appium");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "19");
            //capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "01899dd5c94c237a");
            //capabilities.setCapability("device-orientation", "portrait"); 
            capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
            capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.sat.android");
            capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", ".SatMain");


      try {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
              driver.quit();
```

till now i cant understand what is the problem why logcat is not show responding

kindly help it will be appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by removing the spaces in the path to my sdk folder.
In your case, try renaming your path to

"D:\Softbackup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\" instead of

"D:\Soft backup\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\"

Answer (score 3):

In Mac, when updating to new Android SDK bundled with IntelliJ Android Studio, the sdk path changed to somwthing like `/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk`. The whitespace is making my appium session fails as well. Surprisingly the `appium-doctor` checks didn't give any advice.

I solved it like this

```
ln -s /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk /Users/sergio/Software/android_sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/sergio/Software/android_sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the API level in the `platformVersion` capability and Appium doesn't know what the `version` capability (which you set to `4.4.2`) is, so it ignores it.

```
debug: The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : platform, app-package, app-activity, version
```

You should remove `CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2"` and use `platformVersion` instead.

**Try:**

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
 capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Appium");
 capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
 capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
 //capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
 capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "01899dd5c94c237a");
 //capabilities.setCapability("device-orientation", "portrait"); 
 capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: still having same problem @sheeptest

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your capabilities is that in DeviceName you have to mention "Android"

You have to use capabilities like this:

```
       capabilities.SetCapability("appium-version", "1.2.0");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "4.3");
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Android");
        capabilities.SetCapability("app","--" );
        capabilities.SetCapability("app-package","--" );

        capabilities.SetCapability("app-activity", "--");
```